# why do I have a glitchy effect on my tansition in css?

Tags: css, css-transitions, easeinout

I have a navbar menu, with a class toggled it is collapsed or not, inside this navbar I have small collapsed menus. when I use my navbar normally it work perfectly but when I click on a collapsed menu and that my navbar is collapsed it is supposed to toggle the class to open the navbar, in this second case I don't know why I have those black flash/glitchy effect, Do you know why and how to correct this ?

[image: gif of the issue]

on this gif you can this when I first open the navbar then the menu, then when I open the navbar only clicking on the collapsed menu in the collapsed bar and those glitchy black spot

```css
.sidebar.fliph li a .nav-label, .sidebar.fliph li a .nav-label + span {
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar.fliph {
  width: 42px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.sidebar.fliph li {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar.fliph .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 39px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="navbar.component.ts"></script>
<script src="navbar.component.spec.ts"></script>
<div class="sidebar left" [ngClass]="state ? '':'fliph'" id="navbarcontainer">
    <ul class="list-sidebar bg-defoult">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" id="bouttonmenunavbar" type="button" (click)="switchstate()"> <!--switchsate() switch the value of state and change the class of the nav bar container-->
            <li class="nav-header "><span> <img alt="logo" class="img-circle"
                                                src="../../assets/img/Logo-P3G-Officiel.svg"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </li>
        </button>
        <ul>
            <ul *ngIf="isTeacher()">
                <li><a class="collapsed collapse active" data-target="#TPs" data-toggle="collapse"
                       (click)="unwindOnCollapsed()"><i
                        class="fas fa-file-word"></i><span class="nav-label">TP</span><span
                        class="fa fa-chevron-left float-right"></span></a>
                    <ul class="innerlist sub-menu collapse" id="TPs">
                        <li><a routerLink="/teacher/mytps"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i> Mes Tps</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/teacher/createtp"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i> Créer un TP</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="collapsed collapse active" data-target="#Classes" data-toggle="collapse"
                       (click)="unwindOnCollapsed()"> <!--unwindOnCollapsed() check if the navbar is collapsed and uncollapse it if I click here-->
                    <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span class="nav-label">...</span><span
                        class="fa fa-chevron-left float-right"></span></a>
                    <ul class="innerlist sub-menu collapse" id="Classes">
                        <li>...</li>
                        <li>...</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <li><a
                    (click)="disconnect()" id="disconnected"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span
                    class="nav-label">...</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="nav-label">...</span></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-globe"></i><span class="nav-label">...</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats because you are animating the width, when the words do not fit in the width, the words gonna be displayed in the next line.

Comment: thank you, how can I fix this then ?

Comment: Try set static height and overflow: hidden to li elements

Comment: you can also make a css class for your text elements with display: none and add the ngClass, so that the text go away from ui before the nav width transition. same for opening of the nav.